# Disabling the End Call Key for windows mobile with C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing windows mobile application using with .NET CF 2.0
I want to disabling the End Call 'Key'. when my application running,
This functionality should happen by programming using C#
Can any one Know please help me.

Thanks in advance.
vimal..

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=546737) and focus on the two lines dealing with VK_TEND (0x73).

Comment: Is there a way to enable the they that is blocked by UnregisterFunc1 function?

Comment: http://www.ingenuityworking.com/downloads/developer_sdkhdk/m/sample__demo_code/34822.aspx

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c564aacc-7a63-4c88-8fa8-f8be6892b3f4/how-to-map-the-f3-f4-keys-on-a-windows-mobile-industrial-version?forum=windowsmobiledev